# can not set properties with Session.CustomActionData

Tags: properties, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Can not set a property value using Session.CustomActionData.

```
        if (s.CustomActionData.ContainsKey(PropertyName0))
            s.CustomActionData[PropertyName0] = "1";
        else
            s.CustomActionData.Add(PropertyName0, "1");
```

Although this code works, when the custom action ends, the properties remain unchanged.
So how do I set the property value?
I need to set the property value in one custom action and read it in another.

Comment: Did you try public properties? They don't use lowercase letters in their name, for example PROPERTY_NAME_0.

Comment: Is the custom action Immediate? Deferred actions can only read properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to set a property in a deferred custom action.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370543(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Looking at your answers history at least 10 latest accepted answers was to your own question, are you cheating or...?

Comment: :-D Is it odd to find answer to my own question myself?

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are doing. 
Only few properties are available in the deferred custom action. Are you trying to pass data to a deferred custom action?

You can write an immediate custom action to write properties and then pass these to a deferred custom action if you need this at run time.

Here is an example of an immediate CA

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult ImmediateCA(Session session)
{
   CustomActionData data = new CustomActionData();
   data["property1"] = "abc";
   data["property2"] = "def";
   session["myDeferredCAData"] = data.ToString();
   return ActionResult.Success;
}


[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult myDeferredCA(Session session)
{
   CustomActionData data = session.CustomActionData;
   string property1 = data["property1"];
   return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

This solution is proposed by Nick Ramirez

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks!  I'm using this approach, but wasted hours trying to get my deferred CA to find the data that the immediate CA added, due to KeyNotFoundExceptions.  The trick is that the key in session["key"] needs to be the ID of the deferred CustomAction.  I added this as an edit that hopefully gets approved, so other people don't struggle with that missing little detail.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using managed code for this? I know that I've had trouble with getting C++ CAs to take in a property and update the property in one CA. In the past I've written to the registry in one CA and read from it into a property in another to get around this problem.